# Replace substring in R and conflicts with numeric values

Tags: r, gsub

I want to substitute `" (log2)"` from `"ETS2 (log2)"` but the command I am using is substituting the "2" from "ETS2" as well.

Create character string

```
t = as.character("ETS2 (log2)")
t2 = as.character("ETS1 (log2)")
```

This is the code I tried.

```
    #for t1
    gsub("[ (log2)]", "", t)
    str_replace_all(t, "[[ (log2)]]", "")
    #for t2
    gsub("[ (log2)]", "", t2)
    str_replace_all(t2, "[[ (log2)]]", "")
```

Output:

```
    #for t1
    "ETS "
    "ETS "
    #for t2
    "ETS1 "
    "ETS1 "
```

Desired output:

```
    #for t1
    "ETS2 "
    "ETS2 "
    #for t2
    "ETS1 "
    "ETS1 "
```

Comment: `gsub(" (log2)", "", t, fixed=TRUE)`? Do you really just want to remove a static, hardcoded string of text? Then no need to use a regex.

Comment: Thanks. I was using `gsub("[ (log2)]", "", t, fixed = TRUE)` and thats why did not work.